# Adobe Creative Cloud Color Replacement Tool Not There

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

Color replacement tool in Photoshop CC missing. It's usually behind the brush tool. Just updated and it's still missing. It's there on my desktop Mac, but it's missing on my MacBook Pro.

How do I find where to sync settings and/or find that control on Photoshop?

Comment: I think this would be better addressed by Adobe. We don't even know which CC version or OS you are using.

Comment: Yes, found it on an Adobe forum. I had to change my workspace from photography to essentials.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Edit > Toolbar and in the dialogue that opens click "Restore Defaults".